# How to find the remainder of $\frac{2^{99}}{9}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The question is solved in the book I read in a very odd way as,

> $$\frac{2^{99}}{9} = \dfrac{{(2^{3})}^{33}}{2^3-(-1)}$$
>   Hence by remainder theorem the remainder is $-1$. In questions when remainder is negative than the number is subtracted from numbers like $2^3$ to get a positive number so the answer is $8-{-1}=9$.

I don't know which remainder theorem the book is talking of. I converted the question in mod notation as,

$$2^{99} \bmod 9 = (2^3)^{33} \bmod (2^3 - (-1))$$

But I don't think there is some formula for $a \bmod (c-d)$. Please tell me how to solve these type of questions.

Comment: But $9 = 2^3 + 1 \ne 2^3 - 1$.

Comment: Yes. I don't have the book now just remember a little bit from that.

Comment: Hint: 99 = 3 times 33

Comment: I guess the book is using some theorem in which the denominator is of type $N^x \bmod (N-a) = N-a$ IS there any such formula?

Comment: @OriaGruber I didn't get your hint. I know that $33 \times 3 = 99$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theorem referred to is probably the polynomial remainder theorem. That is that the remainder of $p(x)/(x-a)$ is $p(a)$. So with $p(x) = x^{33}$ and $a=-1$ we have that the remainder of the division will be $p(-1) = (-1)^{33}$. That is:
$$p(x) = x^{33} = (x-(-1))q(x) + (-1)^{33} = (x-(-1))q(x) - 1$$

Inserting $x = 2^3$ into this results in

$$p(2^3) = (2^3-(-1))q(2^3) - 1 = 9q(2^3)-1$$

From this we can see that $2^{99} = 9q(2^3) - 1 = 9q(2^3)-9+8 = 9(q(2^3)-1) + 8$ and since $q$ is a polynomial with integer terms we have that $Q = q(2^3)-1$ is an integer so $2^{99} = 9Q + 8$

---

For proof of the polynomial remainder theorem let $p(x)$ be a polynomial and use euclid division with $x-a$ then we will get a result $q(x)$ and a remainder $r(x)$ of degree one less than $x-a$, that is r(x) is a constant expression $C$. Now the result of the division will be 
 $$p(x) = q(x)(x-a) + r(x) = q(x)(x-a) + C$$.

Now substitute $x$ with $a$ and we get

$$p(a) = q(a)(a-a) + C = 0q(a) + C = C$$

Comment: Only answer so far to actually explain the quote the OP found in his book.

Comment: Aren't Polynomial remainder theorem and Euclid division algorithm different? In polynomial division we subtract powers of $x$ and if the divisor's degree is higher than $2$, say divisor is $x^2+1$ then the remainder will be of type $ax+b$ which exclusively depends upon $x$.

Comment: I also don't get how can the remainder be negative in numerical division, e.g. 33/5 gives remainder 3(i.e. 33-5*6) but if we do 33-(7*5) then we get (-2) as the remainder. But then why does it make sense? Why do 3 and -2 become congurent and help in simplifying calculations?

Comment: but if $q(c)=0$ then $r(c)$ is actually the remainder but still the remainder of polynomial division. How can we show that if q(x) has a degree 1 in x then r(c)[which will obviously be a numeric constant] is same as would be the remainder of Euclid division?

Comment: I know that. In our case the remainder of polynomial division a numeric constant. But why is this constant same as would be the remainder of actual Euclid division performed on actual numbers. BTW I could not understand which degree of denominator are you saying in Euclid division.

Answer (score 6):

$$2^{99} \equiv (2^3)^{33} \equiv 8^{33} \equiv (-1)^{33} \equiv -1 \equiv 8 \pmod 9$$

Comment: Are you using binomial theorem in $8^{33}=(9-(-1))^{33})$?

Comment: No, just $8\equiv -1 \pmod 9$ just the same as in the last step.

Comment: But in the last power we don't have the exponent.

Comment: In which last power?

Comment: Ok, perhaps you are using the fact $8^{33}-(-1)^{33}=[8-(-1)](other terms)=9(other terms)$ so $8$ and $-1$ are congruent with respect to $9$.

Comment: I guess you are thinking to complicated: $8=9-1$ and therefore $8 \equiv 9-1 \equiv 0 -1 \equiv -1 \pmod 9$

Comment: I just did not get how is $8^{33}≡(−1)^{33}$? I understand $8≡-1$ because $8-(-1)$ is divisible by $9$.

Comment: For natural $n$ you have: If $a\equiv b\pmod c$ then $a^n\equiv b^n \pmod c$

Comment: And this would be true only when  $a^n-b^n$ is divisible by $c$ or $a-b$ is divisible by $c$, i.e. $(a-b) \bmod c = 0$.

Comment: (+1) I was about to add $$ \begin{align} 2^{99} &\equiv8^{33}\\ &\equiv(-1)^{33}\\ &\equiv-1\\ &\equiv8\pmod{9} \end{align} $$ when I noticed it was just a vertical version of yours.

Comment: @user103816: Yes of couse, if $a\equiv b \pmod c$ then $(a-b)  \equiv 0 \pmod c$

Answer (score 2):

To solve questions like this, the usual approach is using 
$$\def\mod{\mathbin{\rm mod}} ab \mod n = (a \mod n)(b\mod n) \mod n $$
iteratively. Let's start. We have that 
$$ 2^{99} = 2^{4\cdot 24 + 3} = 8 \cdot 16^{24} $$
reducing modulo $9$, we have 
$$ 2^{99}\mod 9 = 8 \cdot 7^{24} \mod 9 $$
But $7^{24} = 49^{12}$, reducing again and continue in that way
\begin{align*}
  2^{99} \mod 9 &= 49^{12}\cdot 8 \mod 9\\
                &= 4^{12} \cdot 8 \mod 9\\
                &= 16^6 \cdot 8 \mod 9\\
                &= 7^6 \cdot 8 \mod 9\\
                &= 49^3 \cdot 8 \mod 9\\
                &= 4^3 \cdot 8 \mod 9\\
                &= 16^2 \cdot 2 \mod 9\\
                &= 49 \cdot 2 \mod 9\\
                &= 8.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the book was using the geometric sum formula instead
$$
\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^n.
$$
In this way we get
$$
A=\frac{1-(-2^3)^{33}}{1-(-2^3)}=1-2^3+2^6-\ldots+2^{32}\in\mathbb{N}
$$
and
$$
\frac{2^{99}}{9}=\frac{1-(-2^3)^{33}-1}{1-(-2^3)}=A-\frac{1}{9}.
$$